# How can i translate the FTP(Fixed Product Tax)?

Tags: magento2, tax

How can I translate the text that I get FTP that I like the most?

Its not a extension or something, FTP is an attribute that has a product and is different for each product

Magento version 2.2.4

[image]

Comment: Have you tried changing it from backend? Edit your attribute and change labels in manage labels area.

Comment: I set a value to all the views of the labels in manage labels and it does not do anything to me @PrachiSaxena